# How can I get error message?

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection, try-catch

I want to oracle dabase connection with java.
I use this code :

```
url = statement;
try {
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    rset = stmt.executeQuery(url);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // what can I put here?
}
```

And when my statement cause error in oracle I want to get error message.
How can i do this?

Comment: How about looking at the value of `e`? Seems trivial...

Comment: @markus it is right. answer and I tick you

Comment: Please clarify on *want to get error message* - *where* do you want to have it/print it/log it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use e.getMessage();
I believe

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search reveals:

> JDBC Exception handling is very similar to Java Excpetion handling but for JDBC, the most common exception you'll deal with is java.sql.SQLException.

Check out their example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-exceptions.htm)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this piece of code:

```
e.getMessage();
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use `e.getLocalizedMessage()`